# В default методе интерфейса возвращаемое значение может не соответствовать сигнатуре метода?

Tags: java, интерфейс, лямбда-выражение

Тема - лямбда выражения, в контексте паттерна цепочка ответственности. Встретился в сети такой код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@FunctionalInterface
interface RequestHandler {
    public abstract Request handle(Request r);

    default RequestHandler setSuccessor(RequestHandler other) {
        return (req) -> { //req -  it's request            
            System.out.println("req instance of: " +req.getClass().getName());
            return other.handle(this.handle(req));
        };        
    }
}

public class Request {
    String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Request(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Детальнее - есть класс `Request` - в нём только строка, с конструктором и геттером. Есть интерфейс `RequestHandler` - он обработчик запросов. В нём есть абстрактный метод `handle` - для лямбда выражения. И есть метод `setSuccessor` - для более глубоких манипуляций. Вот метод `setSuccessor` вызывает у меня вопросы. Почему он вообще компилится? По сигнатуре, он должен возвращать  RequestHandler, но в первом return (req)  - я выяснил, что req - это просто Request. (Строчка кода  `System.out.println("req instance of: " +req.getClass().getName());` сказала что *req instance of Request*) Во втором `return other.handle(this.handle(req));` - возвращаемое значение, как ни крути, тоже Request, a не RequestHandler! К примеру выражение  `RequestHandler r = other.handle(this.handle(req));` - говорит о несовместимости типов.

**Суммарный вопрос:** где и в какой строке, метод `setSuccessor` умудрился вернуть объект интерфейса `RequestHandler`?

Comment: а как это все запускается? где объявлена `req`?

Comment: req - как я понял, компилятор её назначает из общего контекста. Она здесь нигде не объявлена.

Comment: то есть ты можешь переименовать ее на что угодно и продолжит работать?

Comment: Оно продолжит работать, но тогда в теле метода нужно req тоже поменять. А так - да, это лямбда выражения, Java 8

Comment: аааааа, мне казалось там `return req;` просто, просмотрел что это лямбда ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: тогда вообще все выглядит логично.

Comment: У меня сложилось впечатление, что вы думаете, что возвращается `req`, когда на самом деле возвращается лямбда `return ((req) -> { ... });`. Лямбда - это функция, `req` - её параметр, после `->` идёт тело лямбды. В данном коде лямбда реализует интерфейс `RequestHandler` и его абстрактный метод `handle`.

Comment: уважаемый @IR42 я уже понял, что вы правы. Но нужно бы, какую-то ссылку на техническую литературу (сайт и тому подобное). Дадите ответ -> приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно **java** может возвращать "объект интерфейса", даже если в методе возврата нигде явно не создан такой "объект". "Объект интерфейса" - пишу в кавычках, потому что мы всё равно подразумеваем объект конкретного (часто анонимного) класса, которым управляет интерфейсная ссылка.

До java 8 метод мог вернуть "объект" интерфейса как-то так:

```
public interface Marker { //Интерфейс
   public int doSomething(int x);
}


public Marker m(){ //Метод возвращающий "объект" интерфейса
    return    new Marker(){ //создание объекта и реализация его на базе анонимного класса
        public int doSomething(int x){ //создание конкретной реализации абстрактного метода
            return 25;
        };
    };
}
```

После выхода java 8, чтобы создать "объект интерфейса" нам по прежнему нужно объявить какую-то реализацию метода. Но если в интерфейсе только один абстрактный это можно сделать лямбда выражением:

```
 public Marker m(){ //Тот же метод, c возможностями Java 8
        return x-> 25; //Этой строчкой мы задали конкретную реализацию метода doSomething
    }
```

Что за магия произошла `x-> 25`? В терминах лямбда выражения, мы задали f(x) = 25; f(x) - это конкретная реализация абстрактного метода `doSomething(int x)`; Язык программирования понял это как "из метода `m()` верни мне конкретную реализацию `Marker`, такую что, его единственный абстрактный метод  `doSomething(int x)` станет возвращать константу `{return 25;};` 
То есть, по сути чтобы создать "объект функционального интерфейса" достаточно просто реализовать его абстрактный метод лямбда выражением:

```
Marker m = re->re*2; //Это полностью валидный код. Сказал что реализация метода doSomething(int x){return x*2}
```

Возвращаясь к методу:

```
 default RequestHandler setSuccessor(RequestHandler other) {
        return (req) -> { //req -  это Request компилятор вывел из контекста           
            System.out.println("req instance of: " +req.getClass().getName());
            return other.handle(this.handle(req));
        };        
    }
```

Здесь было сказано "реализация абстрактного метод handle(зависящего от параметра Request) такая, что":

```
handle(Request r){
 System.out.println("r instance of: " +r.getClass().getName());
                return other.handle(this.handle(r));
}
```

И далее, этот метод благополучно вернул "объект интерфейса" RequestHandler с конкретной реализацией данного метода.

Answer (score 1):

Разберитесь, что такое [функциональный интерфейс](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/9.1.php). Чтобы быть `RequestHandler` нужно предоставлять метод с аргументом типа `Request` и возвращаемым значением типа `Request`. Это следует из сигнатуры `handle`. Лямбда-выражение `(req) -> {...}`, грубо говоря, определяет анонимный объект с таким методом. Как вы правильно заметили, параметер `req` имеет тип `Request`, и возвращаемое значение внутри фигурных скобок тоже имеет тип `Request`. Получается этот объект удовлетворяет требованиям `RequestHandler`.

Comment: Вообще не понятные материалы. Так по хорошему из вашей ссылки " функциональный интерфейс должен содержать только один единственный метод без реализации". Но допускается (реально) в функциональном интерфейсе ещё и сколько угодно дефолтных и статических методов. Где мне тут разобраться без разъяснений?

Comment: Да, формулировка не идеальная. Слова "один единственный" относятся именно к методам без реализации. Вы привели код интерфейса `RequestHandler`, у него определён единственный метод без реализации -- `handle`, поэтому он является функциональным интерфейсом, хотя в нём ещё есть дефолтный метод `setSuccessor`.

Comment: В указанной странице, всё же не приводится примера (с разъяснениями) где можно в дефолтном методе указать тип возвращаемого значения - сам тип интерфейса, а потом, в лямбдах вернуть тип, который объявлен абстрактным методом.

Comment: мне стало казаться, что вы не правильно трактуете. Говоря одной строкой, мы в фигурных скобках должны задать не то, что возвращает `RequestHandler`, а тело абстрактного метода, как ни странно.

Comment: Именно так, лямбда-выражение определяет реализацию метода функционального интерфейса.

Comment: Когда уже разобрался, ещё раз перечитал ваш ответ, и понял, что вы тоже понимаете, о чём пишите. Поэтому ставлю вам +1, за искреннее желание помочь. Но принять ответ не могу -> явно не достаточно для человека, зашедшего со стороны.